# Convert image URL to drawable resource id in android

Tags: android, image, android-intent, android-imageview

I'm using the [KenBurnsView](https://github.com/flavioarfaria/KenBurnsView) library with this code:

```
mHeaderPicture.setResourceIds(R.drawable.picture0, R.drawable.picture1);
```

As you can see it takes drawable resource ids.

What I want to do is covert all photos URLS to drawable resource ids.
Photo urls like this:

```
http://example.com/image.jpg
http://example.com/image2.jpg
http://example.com/image3.jpg
http://example.com/image4.jpg
```

I tried this code here and it didn't work:

```
Bitmap drawable_from_url(String url) throws java.net.MalformedURLException, java.io.IOException {
    Bitmap x;

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url) .openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-agent","Mozilla/4.0");

    connection.connect();
    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();

    x = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    return x;
}
```

I have read a LOT of questions and answers all over the web and I didn't find a good tutorial or solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't convert a Bitmap to a resource id. Resource ids are only for resources in your APK. You'll have to edit or extend the [KenBurnsView](https://github.com/flavienlaurent/NotBoringActionBar/blob/master/App/src/main/java/com/flavienlaurent/notboringactionbar/KenBurnsView.java#) class to accept Bitmap objects e.g by adding a function like this:

```
public void setBitmaps(Bitmap... bitmaps) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mImageViews.length; i++) {
        mImageViews[i].setImageBitmap(bitmaps[i]);
    }
}
```

Then you can pass the Bitmaps that you load with drawable_from_url()

Comment: WOW, Worked like Charm, Thank You Very Much :)

Answer (score 3):

Try to drop this library into your project. Its a useful library.
http://square.github.io/picasso/

Sample Usage:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://example.com/image.jpg").into(imageView);
```

How to get the drawable from imageView:

```
Drawable myDrawable = imageView.getDrawable();
```

Comment: im using this library in my project, Please read the question carefully this question is using KenBurnsView and the only way to set the images inside is using resource id which is Int[]

Comment: Do you know is it possible to convert to Drawable directly from Picasso?, without load into a image view? @icaneatclouds

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to add setDoInput to connection

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add asynchronous task ...

```
new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1))
            .execute(url);
}
public void onClick(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, IndexActivity.class));
    finish();
}
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView mHeaderPicture;
public DownloadImageTask(ImageView mHeaderPicture){
        this.mHeaderPicture= mHeaderPicture;
    }  protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        mHeaderPicture.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}`
```

Make sure you have the following permissions set in your AndroidManifest.xml to access the internet.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: whats this ??!! this question is not even related to the question :-s